# Change intIndex to timedeltaIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, timedelta

My index:

```
Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
            17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
           dtype='int64')
```

I would like to make it as:

```
timedelta64[ns]([0:00, 1:00, 2:00, 3:00 ... %H:%M])
```

I tried it:

```
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index)
```

But this just changes to: `00:00:00.000000` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) or [`TimedeltaIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html) with parameter `unit`:

```
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='H')
```

Or:

```
df.index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.index, unit='H')
```

Sample:

```
a = pd.Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
            17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])

b = pd.to_timedelta(a, unit='H')
print (b)
TimedeltaIndex(['00:00:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00',
                '05:00:00', '06:00:00', '07:00:00', '08:00:00', '09:00:00',
                '10:00:00', '11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00', '14:00:00',
                '15:00:00', '16:00:00', '17:00:00', '18:00:00', '19:00:00',
                '20:00:00', '21:00:00', '22:00:00', '23:00:00'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thank you! I keep missing the basics about time :/